# how to change the response of a datatable?, laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, server, datatables

I have my project in laravel stored in a subdirectory and I am using datatables, however, when I want to recover the information, I get the typical error "invalid json" , my project url is as follows

http://www.loupper.com/loupper-b/public/

but the answer I get is this

> **http://www.loupper.com/subcategory/data**?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=checkmark&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=id&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=subcategoria&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=subcategoria&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=categoria&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=categoria&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=action&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=action&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=1&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=desc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1505922295346

it seems, the route has not taken the subdirectories "loupper-b/public/" ,how could I add subdirectories to the url?

this is my code, jquery

```
$(function () {
$.noConflict();

user_tbl = $('#categoria-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    order: [[1, 'desc']],
    ajax: {
        url: '/category/data',
        data: function (d) {
          d.filter = $('select[name=filter]').val();

        },

    },
    columns: [
        {data: 'checkmark', name:'id', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        {data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false, class:"text-center"}
    ]
});

$('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    user_tbl.draw();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
     });

   });
```

laravel

```
public function indexDatatable()
{
    $categoria=DB::table("categoria")->select("id","nombre")->get();

    return Datatables::of($categoria)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($categoria) {

                return '<button onClick=deleteCategoria('.$categoria->id.'); type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-id="'.$categoria->id.'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button><a href="/categoria/edit/'.$categoria->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary f-left"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';

    })
   ->editColumn('checkmark', function($categoria) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk[]" class="case" value="'.$categoria->id.'">';
     })

    ->rawColumns(['checkmark','action'])
    ->make(true);

}
```

Comment: Post the javascript in which you are trying to get it done.

Comment: hi adnan, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

you can use `url('/category/data')` to the get it running.

```
user_tbl = $('#categoria-table').DataTable({
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
order: [[1, 'desc']],
ajax: {
    url: '{{url('/category/data')}}',
    data: function (d) {
      d.filter = $('select[name=filter]').val();

    },

},
columns: [
    {data: 'checkmark', name:'id', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    {data: 'nombre', name: 'nombre'},
    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false, class:"text-center"}
]
});
```

Comment: the response now is http://www.loupper.com/loupper-b/public/%7B%7Burl('/category/data')%7D%7D?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I only had to remove the first slash:

```
ajax: {
  url: 'category/data',
}
```